# Working with 2 databases and just one entity manager in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entitymanager

I need to keep an archive database to an application in Symfony2.
In it I'll keep all records older than 90 days. I was thinking that I could use just one entity manager (because both databases are identical).

First of all, I'm not sure if this is the best approach/solution.
And, besides that, I don't know how to implement this idea (I've just found 2 entity managers for 2 databases).

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I've been looking for some solution for it for 2 days now.

Comment: Basically you can't use two databases and one manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, each Entity Manager can only use one DB connection, [the docs seem quite clear about it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

So I think you'll be stuck with using two EMs.  Each will be configured with a duplicate set of your mappings.  The detail of how you use them is up to you though:

- You could just manually choose one or the other as required in your app
- You could somehow abstract it away into a class of your own which has both EMs, and then when you run queries etc it will be worrying about where to get the data from (and possibly how to combine data from both EMs)
- If the only activity which really needs both EMs is the archive process itself, that's an obvious thing to hide away in a class nicely

I suppose it also depends on what the point of the archive DB is.  If it's some architectural thing like it needs to be on a different server or whatever, then you're stuck as above.  On the other hand, if you really just want old data not to show up in day-to-day queries (without specifically asking for it), then it might be better to implement some kind of "archived" flag and a Doctrine Extension which magically hides archived items away until you ask for them, very similar to [SoftDeleteable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md)

Comment: Regarding the documentation, I've read it a few times before bother you with my question. Nevertheless, it didn't seem clear to me that I couldn't have it working. And @musaya said it could work (it's working for him). Anyway, your solution looks quite nice for my problem and I appreciate it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

We use distinct em for saving history, works fine. 
Code looks like this.

Somewhere **in your config**...

**yourpath\app\config\parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: site1.ru
    database_port: 3346
    database_name: db1
    database_user: roof
    database_password: jump

    database_history_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_history_host: site2.ru
    database_history_port: 10001
    database_history_name: history
    database_history_user: sea
    database_history_password: deep

    etc...
```

Somewhere **in your history bundle**...

```
/**
 * We make history!
 **/
class historyController extends Controller
{
    public function showAction($historyId)
    {
        // get secondary manager
        $emHistory = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('history');
        // get default manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
    }
}
```

Somewhere **in services of history bundle**

```
class HistoryBundleUtils {
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($arguments) {
        // get secondary manager
        $this->em = $arguments['entityManager']->getManager('history');
        # etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a good practice but I have been using one EM for two Databases successfully in Symfony2. The project I was working on required access to two databases. There are some limitations however. First the database_user and _password needs to be the same for both databases. You can access both databases, but you can only create (with console doctrine:database:create) and write the tables (console doctrine:schema:update) of the one defined in parameters.yml.
You can read, write, update, delete on both databases, but you need to specify the database name of your second database in the model, like:

```
@ORM\Table(name="my_other_database.my_table")
```

Basically, you can use one EM for two Databases, if one database already exists and you only need to access it.

Comment: That seems interesting!  Don't think it would work for the questionner's use case though - each database contains a full set of the same tables, you can't put some of them in one DB and some in the other, it's the rows that are made separate.  You could possibly duplicate all your entities, but that's sounding a bit crazy...

Comment: It seems really nice. I really think that I found a more suitable solution for my case in Doctrine Extension (@frumious answer) but thank you for your help...